# Why the output is incorrect

Tags: c, arduino-ide, arduino-c++, arduino-esp32

I have this code but I don't know what happen why the result of `out` is incorrect any advice please?

```
int *getarray(int *out)  
{  
    int data[20];  
    for(int i=0;i<20;i++)  
    {  
       data[i]=i;
    } 
    for(int i=0;i<20;i++)  
    {  
       out+=data[i]; 
    }  
    Serial.printf("out inside getarray = %d",out);

    return data;  
}  

void resultdata(){
  int *n;  
  int out;
  n=getarray(&out); 
  Serial.printf("out = %d",out);   
} 
void setup() {
  // Init Serial Monitor
  Serial.begin(115200);
 resultdata();
}
```

Comment: `return data;` returns a pointer to the _local_ array `data` which won't exist anymore once the `getarray` has ended. But right, here you don't use `n` in `resultdata` so this does actually not matter. Anyway, be aware that after `n = getarray(&out);`, `n` does not point to valid data.

Comment: the function getarray doesn't change the variable "out" in the function resultdata

Comment: How to solve this problem please? I need to return the "data" and "out" at the same time.

Comment: You need to study how parameter passing to functions work in your beginner-level book. This isn't how. Both variables and parameters are local to the function.

Comment: Please choose a title which actually describes your problem, as to help others with the same issue.

Comment: Also [edit] and explain in plain english what `getarray` is supposed to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two problems:

- The `data` array in `getarray` will cease to exist once the `getarray` function has finished execution.
- You need to dereference `out` in order to change the `out` in `resultdata`. Read again the chapter dealing with pointers in your learning material.

You probably want something like this:

```
int *getarray(int *out, int *data)  
{  
    // remove this   int data[20];  
    *out = 0;            // you need to dereference the out pointer
                         // and initialize it to 0

    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)  
    {  
       data[i] = i;      // you need to dereference the out pointer
       *out += data[i]; 
    } 

    // I'm not sure why you have this second loop here,
    // it looks pretty pointless
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)  
    {  
       *out += data[i];  // you need to dereference the out pointer
    }

    Serial.printf("*out inside getarray = %d", *out);

    return data;  
}

void resultdata(){
  int *n;  
  int out;
  int data[20];              // declare the data array here
  n = getarray(&out, data);  // pass address of the data array
                             // so that getarray can fill the data array
  Serial.printf("out = %d", out);   
}
```